# How to open sub menu by key pressing

Tags: cocoa

While menu is shown, I would like to open sub menu for menu item by key pressing.
I know osx menu doesn't work like this, but I need this feature.
Who can help me to do it with cocoa api?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get full source written in objective-c for osx menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679870/where-can-i-get-full-source-written-in-objective-c-for-osx-menu)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for a single keystroke to select/open a submenu, but if not then the arrows keys will do what you ask: up/down selects an item in a menu, right/left enters/exits submenus. You can also type the first letter(s) of a menu item to jump to an item quicker.

So control-F2 gets you to the menu bar, right/left to a menu, down/up into & around the menu, first letter(s) jump you to an item, and within a menu right/left gets you into a submenu - full keyboard access.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am finding way to open sub menu with one operation, not to select and open.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but you could try invoking `NSMenu`'s `-performActionForItemAtIndex:` with the index of the submenu.